# ODI - Working with structured file.txt (record father and sons)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-data-integrator

I have a file.txt to elaborate with ODI which is made up of several records with the following structure:

- Heather Record (father)

  - record type 1 (son)
  - record type 2 (son)
  - record type 1...n (son)
  - record type 2...n (son)
- Footer Record 1
- Heather Record (father1)

  - record type 1 (son)
  - record type 2 (son)
  - record type 1...n (son)
  - record type 2...n (son)
- Footer Record 2

Each record contains a set of common fields after which each one has its own structure. For this reason I have to create several tables into my database for each record type and a Fact Table which store the ralationship among each record. Doing so, I don't know how to keep the relationship among the record father and sons. Is it possible to use some function in ODI to do that? Is it possible to import the file with ODI and elaborate a sort of hierarchical system?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider doing a preliminary import in a temporary table where, depending on the kind of row (header, type1 son, type2 son or footer), you populate two new columns `RECORD_ID` and `ROW_TYPE`.

1. `RECORD_ID` would be populated via a sequence, using `nextVal()` when the row type is header and `lastVal()` in the other cases.
2. `ROW_TYPE` would be populated with the row type.

In this way you could later on populate your tables based on the value of `ROW_TYPE`, preserving the relationship between father and sons in the `RECORD_ID` column.

**Edit (further explaination)**

Let's say your files' rows have the following structure

```
Header: Field1;Field2;Field3
Type1: Field1;Field2
Type2: Field1;Field2;Field3;Field4
Footer: Field1;Field2
```

Then your target tables would require a column for each field in the corresponding file row, plus one for the ID. They would look like this

```
Header
ID | Header col1 | Header col2 | Header col3

Type1
ID | Type1 col1 | Type1 col2

Type2
ID | Type2 col1 | Type2 col2 | Type2 col3 | Type2 col4

Footer
ID | Footer col1 | Footer col2
```

Then your temporary table would have 6 columns (5 from the table that has more, plus one for the `Type`) and would look like this

```
Temp
Type | ID | Temp col1 | Temp col2 | Temp col3 | Temp col4
```

With this structure, you could have a first interface that loads every row of the file in the table, putting in the `Type` column a different value depending on the row you're analyzing, and the proper call to the sequence (`nextVal()` or `lastVal()`) in the `ID` column.

```
Temp interface

Type <- rowType
ID <- case when rowType = Header then sequence.nextVal() else sequence.lastVal() end
Temp col1 <- File field1
Temp col2 <- File field2
Temp col3 <- File field3
Temp col4 <- File field4
```

Then you could have multiple interfaces that from this temporary table would populate one target table each, filtering on the Type column.

```
Header interface

ID <- ID
Header col1 <- Temp col1
Header col2 <- Temp col2
Header col3 <- Temp col3
where Type = 'Header'
```

Comment: This solution could work! But, once I created the table t1(RECORD_ID , ROW_TYPE), how can I fill the column RECORD_ID using ODI? Is it possible to populate both columns at the same time? because I need to know first the value of row type column in order to fill RECORD_ID fields

Comment: Sorry, my answer wasn't clear at all... I edited it with further explaination, hope my solution is applicable to your case.